# Ставится ли запятая между определениями?

Tags: пунктуация

Хорошее качественное видео.

Ставится ли запятая между определениями? Если да, то почему? Если нет, то тоже почему?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***Хорошее, качественное видео***.

1) Отношения между определениями **однородные,**  сближенные по значению (запятая ставится). В этом случае определения раскрывают одну **общую тему**, выступают как контекстуальные **синонимы**: *хорошее видео — это качественное видео.*

2) **Если считать их неоднородными,** то первое определение ***хорошее*** должно относиться к сочетанию ***качественное видео,*** и тогда поучается: ***хорошее (качественное видео)***, но ведь не существует ***плохого (качественного видео).***

3) Поэтому **здесь не может быть неоднородных отношений**, и  оба определения относятся к существительному, между собой они независимы.

4) Соответственно,  неверно считать, что это задача имеет два решения: **запятая между определениями однозначно не ставится.**

5) Правило Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

Согласованные определения являются неоднородными, если предшествующее определение относится не непосредственно к существительному, **а к сочетанию последующего определения с этим существительным:** Алёша подал ему маленькое складное кругленькое зеркальце (Дост.) — ср.: кругленькое зеркальце — складное кругленькое зеркальце — маленькое складное кругленькое зеркальце;

Answer (score 0):

Не "обособляется", а разделяются ли запятой эти определения. Можно разделить, можно не разделять. Зависит от всего, и не в последнюю очередь - от желания самого автора.

Мне больше нравится разделить. Ищите тему "Однородные и неоднородные определения".